# how to create a scroll down table

Tags: html, css, github, web, e-commerce

can someone help me to create a scroll down table like the menu bar at ebay.com, like when I click fashion it will show subcategories like this
[image]
, what I'm doing has only 2 subcomponents. this is my UX/UI
[image]
I also coded the homepage, here is the code link: https://github.com/tranluongtiensi/code_fe_2

create a scroll down table

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp

Answer (score 1):

that's a clickable dropdown menu , as you can see here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Either way you have the code to do it here!

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```